# Regex 2 digits separated by commas, not all required

Tags: regex

I need a regex for the following input:

> [2 digits], comma, [two digits], comma, [two digits]

The 2 digits cannot start with 0. It is allowed to only enter the first 2 digits. Or to enter the first 2 digits, then a comma en then the next 2 digits. Or to enter the full string as described above.

Valid input would be:

> 10
>   99
>   17,56
>   15,99
>   10,57,61
>   32,44,99

Could anyone please help me with this regex?

At the moment I have this regex, but it doesn't limit the input to maximum 3 groups of 2 digits:

```
^\d{2}(?:[,]\d{2})*$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
^[1-9]\d(?:,[1-9]\d){0,2}$
```

The first part (`[1-9]\d`) is simply the first number, which has to be present at all times. It consists of a non-zero digit and an arbitrary second digit (`\d`).

What follows is a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`), containing a comma followed by another two-digit number (`,[1-9]\d`), just alike the first one. This group can be repeated between zero and two times (`{0,2}`), so you get either no, one or two sequences of a comma and another number.

You can easily expand the part in the curly braces to allow for more allowed numbers.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But could you please explain how it works exactly? And would it be possible to expand on my regex to make it work as required? ^\d{2}(?:[,]\d{2})*$

Comment: @iar: You can use back-ticks in comments to format source-code.

Comment: I think iar wants this: `^[1-9]\d(?:,\d\d){0,2}$`

Comment: Thank @Johannes Rössel for explaining my code. @iar I'm not sure what are exactly you asking.

Comment: @stefita: never mind, I asked to change the regex I came up with (in my question), to make it work as required.
@Johannes Rössel: thans for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[1-9]\d([,][1-9]\d){0,2}$
```

Comment: You don't need `[]` around a single character. A single `,` is exactly the same as the character class `[,]`.

Comment: from experience I've found it better to be safe than sorry. Therefore I always use [] around special characters such as ',' '.' '$' '#'  etc.

Comment: , - is not special character. Regular Expressions already is a hard to read/understand language, so adding unnecessary characters to already complicated expressions is bad idea. But +1 for working answer.