# What would be the regex pattern for a set of numbers separated with a comma

Tags: regex

The possible values are...

```
1 (it will always start with a number)
1,2
4,6,10
```

Comment: This question will be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553568/regex-2-digits-separated-by-commas-not-all-required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
(\d+,?)+
```

Comment: If it has to match at least one number, that should be a + rather than *

Comment: In other way this same as a string of numbers contain comma not consecutive. Then first + can be omitted `(\d+,?)+` -> `(\d,?)+`

Comment: @pinichi: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean that can be more shorter, Ex: "11,2" can be express as [(1)(1)(,)](2) in `(\d+,?)+` case and as (1)(1,)(2) in `(\d,?)+` also.

Comment: (\d,?)+ will only match single digit numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) -- It won't match double-or-greater digit numbers: 10,12,23,100,45 my answer was "(one or more digits optionally followed by comma) one or more times"

Comment: It will match multiple digit numbers - "10," would be parsed as (1)(0,)  - but i will also match a trailing comma

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
-?[0-9]+(,-?[0-9]+)*
```

Or, if you want to be pedantic and disallow numbers starting with 0 (other than 0 itself):

```
(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)(,(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*))+
```

Floating-point numbers are left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want

(?<=(?:,|^))\d+(?=(?:$|,))

Regex Buddy explains it as...

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=(?:,|^))»

Match the regular expression below «(?:,|^)»

```
  Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «,»

     Match the character "," literally «,»

  Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «^»

     Assert position at the start of the string «^»
```

Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»

Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»

Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=(?:$|,))»

Match the regular expression below «(?:$|,)»

```
  Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «$»

     Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»

  Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «,»

     Match the character "," literally «,»
```

I would explain it as,  "match any string of digits confirming that before it comes either the start of the string or a comma and that after it comes either the end of the string or a comma".  nothing else.

The important thing is to use non-capturing groups (?:) instead of simply () to help overall performance.